# uniform convergence of sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} , x \in \mathbb{R}$

Is $f_n$ uniformly convergent on $ \ [\frac{1}{2},1\ ] $?

1) If $x=\frac{1}{n}$,  $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}$
 but  $x=\frac{1}{n}$ does not  belong to the set $ \ [\frac{1}{2},1\ ] $

2) I know that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$ on $ \ [\frac{1}{2},1\ ] $

3) $f_n$ is defined on a closed and bounded interval so supremum of $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert $ is attained for each x.

To find sup, let $f'_n(x)=0$. This gives $\frac{-2n^2x}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}=0$ which gives $x=0.$   How to conclude for supremum?

How do we prove it converges uniformly on $ \ [\frac{1}{2},1\ ] $?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$|f_n(x) -0| \leqslant \frac{1}{1 + n^2(1/2)^2}$$

Comment: which tends to 0 as $ n\rightarrow \infty$ and hence limsup$\vert f_n(x)-0\vert \rightarrow 0 $ as  $ n\rightarrow \infty$ and hence uniformly continuous.right?

Comment: @dipalimali: Yes that is correct.